# How to properly build REST API for Grails applications that uses Facebook authorization?

Tags: facebook, api, grails

I have a Facebook application that opens Grails site it IFRAME.
It build upon Spring Security Facebook Plugin.
Now I need to create mobile App that interacts with my site.

I have a controller Api and REST actions, for example:

`http://localhost/api/getArticles`

I want to add security restriction for this action: only authenticated users can get articles:

```groovy
@Secured(["hasRole('ROLE_FACEBOOK')"])
class ApiController {
    def getArticles() {
        render(Article.list() as JSON)
    }
}
```

OK, how can I achive this?
The mobile application makes authorization in FB, then it get access_token.
Then it makes call of [Json Authentication](http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/single.html#3.5%20Json%20Authentication).
What I need to add for all requests to make requests to Api controller automaticly authorized?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile app usually use OAuth2 (more ofter some kind of custom/simplified version) to access server API.

And JSON Authentication supposed to be used as an exchange point for token exchange. Basically, you have to send a FB token to app, server will create/auth fb user and send an OAuth token for following requests.